# What does this class definition ~Class() in c#

Tags: c#, idisposable

I am trying to implement a iDisposable class and I saw a code like that

```
public class Foo: IDisposable 
{

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Does Something.
    }

    ~Foo()
    {

    }
}
```

what does ~Foo()?

Comment: `~Foo()` is a desctructor

Comment: @Nilesh: It's a *finalizer* in C#.

Comment: [Mandatory reading about `IDisposable`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/1864167).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Msdn, it has a really good and simple example what a destructor does
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is a [Finalizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s71x931%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its purpose is to clean up any unmanaged resources the class holds. There is a whole lot of information to learn about what Finalizers are for and how they work.

Comment: `IDisposable` is probably a better fit for such things and the finalizer would just call `Dispose()` in case it wasn't called previously.

Comment: My point was that there is a whole theory around how the Garbage Collector handles types that implement a Finalizer.